# notepad++ - How to choose editor background color for a specific language?

Tags: notepad++, colors, language

How can I set the background color of the editor for a specific language in notepad++?

I know there are similar question on *superuser* but they don't solve the following problem I have:

If I change all the background colors in let's say the Python color settings, it only changes the background color where text/code is, but the rest of the editor still uses the default background color.

How can I change the background so that, for example in an opened .py file, all of the editor background has the same color and in another language it has another color?

Comment: It's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

As the above commenter said, normally it is not possible.

BUT

if you really

really really really want this

then you can achieve this by a workaround:

1. At [Notepad++ Download page](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/), choose download called `Notepad++ zip package`
2. Extract the archive multiple times, e.g. into

   `C:\Tools\Notepad++\Python\
   C:\Tools\Notepad++\XML\
   C:\Tools\Notepad++\SQL\`
3. [Configure file associations](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-default-programs#1TC=windows-7) of desired file types to open in desired instances of Notepad++. E.g. let `.py` files open with `C:\Tools\Notepad++\Python\notepad++.exe` and `.xml` files open with `C:\Tools\Notepad++\XML\notepad++.exe`. So double-clicking a `.py` file will open different Notepad++ than double-clicking of `.xml` file.
4. Now, each of your Notepad++ instances can have its own background settings, indentation settings and any normally-impossible-per-file-type settings you want.

---

UPDATE: in your profile, you say you are hobby programmer. So if you wish, you can [write your plugin for Notepad++ – it can be possibly done in less than 10 minutes](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/contribute/plugin-howto.html).

Comment: I was hoping for a solution to use different backgrounds in different tabs of the same application instance, rather than having to open a new instance for each file type. Maybe a future version of notepad++ will support individual background color for each file type.

Comment: @uzumaki – Ineed, my answer was for case if you *really* need it. If it is only a "*nice to have*" feature you request with all the comfort, then as I wrote at the beginning, there is no way. Of course, you can always add the feature into Notepad++ by yourself. Or fill a [feature request](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues). Again, in case if you would ***really*** need this, isn't that small compromise with comfort in order to achieve color backgrounds acceptable?

Comment: @uzumaki – you was hoping for something different, but you did not indicate that constraint it in the question. So now, if you have answer fully-covering all viewpoints (1-not possible; 2-alternative way; 3-what will surely work) maybe it could be fair to accept it, don't you think?